# Kotlin `use` with AutoCloseable type and a lambda returning Boolean

Tags: kotlin, try-with-resources, autocloseable, closeable

This must be simple, but I've been banging my head against it for half an hour now... Here's my old, exception-unsafe code:

```
fun isReady(): Boolean {
    try {
        val cc: CommandChannel = getCommandChannel()  // implements AutoCloseable
        cc.writeMessage("blahblah")
        val response = cc.readMessage()  // might throw
        cc.close()
        if (response.error == null) {
            return true
        }
    } catch (e: ChannelConnectionException) {
    }
    return false
}
```

I'd like to rewrite it to use `use`, something like this:

```
fun isReady(): Boolean {
    getCommandChannel().use {
        try {
            it.writeMessage("blahblah")
            if (it.readMessage().error == null) {
                return true
            }
        } catch (e: ChannelConnectionException) {
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

But Kotlin gives me an error:

```
[ERROR] X.kt:[108,29] Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
[ERROR] @InlineOnly public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> ???.use(block: (???) -> ???): ??? defined in kotlin.io
[ERROR] X.kt:[110,17] Unresolved reference: it
[ERROR] X.kt:[111,21] Unresolved reference: it
[ERROR] X.kt:[112,21] 'return' is not allowed here
[ERROR] X.kt:[116,13] 'return' is not allowed here
[ERROR] X.kt:[118,5] A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Or, I say "okay I don't understand terse lambda syntax, let me use `fun`," and I try this:

```
fun isReady(): Boolean {
    return getCommandChannel().use(fun(cc: CommandChannel): Boolean {
        try {
            cc.writeMessage("blahblah")
            if (cc.readMessage().error == null) {
                return true
            }
        } catch (e: ChannelConnectionException) {
        }
        return false
    })
}
```

Kotlin still complains:

```
[ERROR] X.kt:[108,36] Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
[ERROR] @InlineOnly public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> ???.use(block: (???) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.io
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

My current guess is that the problem is that the `CommandChannel` I'm trying to use implements `AutoCloseable` instead of `Closeable`... but I don't know what I'm supposed to do about that! (Is there some sort of adaptor I need to wrap it in, maybe?) Fundamentally, I just want to make sure that `cc`'s `close` method gets called correctly at the end of `cc`'s scope, so that I'm not leaking connections.

Comment: This may help: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/try-with-resources

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Kotlin source,

```
public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R
```

is available in `kotlin-stdlib` package ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Closeable.kt)), whereas

```
public inline fun <T : AutoCloseable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R
```

is available in `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jdk7/src/kotlin/AutoCloseable.kt)) package.

So, the error that you get :

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
[ERROR] @InlineOnly public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> ???.use(block: (???) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.io
```

indicates that since `CommandChannel` implements `AutoCloseable` and not `Closeable`, the `use` function appropriate to that is not available in your project. **Try adding the dependency of [kotlin-stdlib-jdk8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8) or [kotlin-stdlib-jdk7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7)** and you should then be able to *use* `.use{}` for `CommandChannel`.

Comment: As for the next error, you need to use `return@use` instead of `return` inside the lambda.